# list all images in directory in JSON

Tags: php, json

I need away to list all images in a directory in a CLEAN json format. I need it to look like this:

```
URLLINK:"image of where the image is"
```

That is all I need.

Comment: to do this first read all the images form a directory, that will return the name and just encode that into json format..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$files = array();

$dir = opendir('/tmp');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $files[] = $file;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($files);
```

Something like this.
You can convert it in any structure you want

Answer (score 11):

A one line code would be:

```
echo json_encode(glob("*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE));
```

References:

- [PHP: glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)
- [Glob Patterns for File Matching in PHP](http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/)

Comment: Coool, but I would still add headers :)

Comment: That's a gem! Do you know how to add recursion to that to also list subfolders?

Comment: Simply awesome! Thank you!